# Three separate radio buttons calling upon different sounds

Tags: android, radio-button, android-mediaplayer

I have had this error with checkbox functionality as well. No error is produced but the functionality shows that a piece of my code is either not being reached or not being read correctly.

Here is the specific snippet that I wish to address:

```
  public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        final RadioButton softLoud = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.low_to_high_radioButton);
        final RadioButton loudSoft = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.high_to_low_radioButton);
        final RadioButton verbalCommand = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.step_voice_radioButton);
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        if (verbalCommand.isChecked()){
            verbalCommand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                    }
                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                        AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor;
                        //Change mp3 file using voice recorder when ready
                        assetFileDescriptor = getAssets().openFd("Noise.mp3");
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(assetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                                assetFileDescriptor.getStartOffset(),
                                assetFileDescriptor.getLength());
                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                          }
                      });
                    } else if(softLoud.isChecked()){
                        softLoud.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                ToneGenerator toneG = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 50);
                                toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 200);

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The idea is that I have three radio buttons (only two shown here) one of the buttons calls upon a self-recorded .mp3 file and the other creates a beep pattern increasing in volume (the increasing in volume isn't shown because I feel this issue needs to be resolved first, I am researching delays currently). When the app is run only one of the if statements executes, for example, if I click the beep first it will always beep but the voice recording won't work and visa versa. 
Also, should this be in onStart, onCreate, or onResume?

Here is the full Activity:

```
public class AudioActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio);
        //load preferred values
        loadPrefs();


        //Once audio is checked press ok button to return to feedback activity
        //initialize the radio buttons
        final RadioButton softLoud = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.low_to_high_radioButton);
        final RadioButton loudSoft = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.high_to_low_radioButton);
        final RadioButton verbalCommand = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.step_voice_radioButton);

        Button audioOkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.audio_ok);
        if (audioOkButton != null && (softLoud.isChecked() || loudSoft.isChecked() || verbalCommand.isChecked())) {
            audioOkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(AudioActivity.this, FeedbackActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        } else if (audioOkButton != null && !(softLoud.isChecked() || loudSoft.isChecked() || verbalCommand.isChecked())) {
            audioOkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    showSimplePopUp();
                }
            });
        }
            //function call to have a response when button clicked
            CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener checker = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    //save button preference
                    savePrefs("softLoudAudio", softLoud.isChecked());
                    savePrefs("loudSoftAudio", loudSoft.isChecked());
                    savePrefs("verbalCommandAudio", verbalCommand.isChecked());
                }
            };
            softLoud.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checker);
            loudSoft.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checker);
            verbalCommand.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checker);
        }


    private void loadPrefs() {
         RadioButton softLoud = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.low_to_high_radioButton);
         RadioButton loudSoft = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.high_to_low_radioButton);
         RadioButton verbalCommand = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.step_voice_radioButton);
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        //Creates a cache with default value of false
        boolean softLoudValue = sp.getBoolean("softLoudAudio", false);
        boolean loudSoftValue = sp.getBoolean("loudSoftAudio", false);
        boolean verbalCommandValue = sp.getBoolean("verbalCommandAudio", false);

        if(softLoudValue){
            softLoud.setChecked(true);
        }else if(loudSoftValue){
            loudSoft.setChecked(true);
        }else if(verbalCommandValue){
            verbalCommand.setChecked(true);
        }else{
            softLoud.setChecked(false);
            loudSoft.setChecked(false);
            verbalCommand.setChecked(false);
        }
    }

    private void savePrefs(String key, boolean value) {
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
        edit.putBoolean(key, value);
        edit.commit();
    }

    private void showSimplePopUp() {

        AlertDialog.Builder helpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        helpBuilder.setTitle(R.string.oops);
        helpBuilder.setMessage(R.string.error_message);
        helpBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Do nothing but close the dialog
                    }
                });

        // Remember, create doesn't show the dialog
        AlertDialog helpDialog = helpBuilder.create();
        helpDialog.show();
    }
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        final RadioButton softLoud = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.low_to_high_radioButton);
        final RadioButton loudSoft = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.high_to_low_radioButton);
        final RadioButton verbalCommand = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.step_voice_radioButton);
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        if (verbalCommand.isChecked()){
            verbalCommand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                    }
                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                        AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor;
                        //Change mp3 file using voice recorder when ready
                        assetFileDescriptor = getAssets().openFd("Noise.mp3");
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(assetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                                assetFileDescriptor.getStartOffset(),
                                assetFileDescriptor.getLength());
                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                          }
                      });
                    } else if(softLoud.isChecked()){
                        softLoud.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                ToneGenerator toneG = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 50);
                                toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 200);

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why but I fixed the issue using only one onClick method rather than the two I have posted:

```
public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        final RadioButton softLoud = ((RadioButton) this.findViewById(R.id.low_to_high_radioButton));
        final RadioButton loudSoft = (RadioButton) this.findViewById(R.id.high_to_low_radioButton);
        final RadioButton verbalCommand = (RadioButton) this.findViewById(R.id.step_voice_radioButton);
        softLoud.setOnClickListener(this);
        verbalCommand.setOnClickListener(this);
        loudSoft.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        int id = view.getId();
        if (id == R.id.step_voice_radioButton) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            try {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor;
                //Change mp3 file using voice recorder when ready
                assetFileDescriptor = getAssets().openFd("Noise.mp3");
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(assetFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                        assetFileDescriptor.getStartOffset(),
                        assetFileDescriptor.getLength());
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (id == R.id.low_to_high_radioButton) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            ToneGenerator toneG = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 50);
            toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 700);
        } else if(id == R.id.high_to_low_radioButton) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            ToneGenerator tones = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 100);
            tones.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 1000);
        }
    }
```